# After xfs repair, only files from root user are accessible

Tags: xfs, failed

After a power failure during server installation of CentOS, the external storage  system that contains user data could not be mounted due to failed superblocks. I performed an xfs_repair on the system, which worked fine, but only the directories that are owned by root appear after the file system is mounted.

The file system is a Dell MD3200 with 4 LUNS that are assembled in raid 0 via mdadm. Prior to the power outage, the LUNS were detected as /dev/dm-0, /dev/dm-1, etc. After the xfs_repair they appear as /dev/sd* instead as the LUNS are no longer recognized as virtual disks (generated by Dell MDSA).

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: There really isn't enough info here to be able to suggest anything specific.  An `xfs_repair` won't change how devices are presented to the OS, so I suspect you've got something "deeper" going on.

Comment: Why were the LUNs arranged in RAID-0 like this? It sounds like this was a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the raid 0 was decided by a third party. Thanks for the comments, I think the problem is not solvable and the data will be lost.